# What is the consideration in marriage in Islam?

Tags: nikah, prophet-muhammad

This is a followup question to another popular question here: [Does Islam support pedophilia or child marriages?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22982/does-islam-support-pedophilia-or-child-marriages)

A lot of the answers say, age is not a consideration in marriage, since the time of consummation (which is when puberty starts) is separate from marriage and can be years apart.

The example given in the example in previous question was, Muhammad married Ayesha when she was 6, but they did not consummate the marriage until she was 9, which, presumably is when she began puberty.  (Let's forget the argument as to whether a pre-pubescence child can consent to marriage).

So what are the qualities people look at in marriage?  Just family unions and relations and religious ties?  Or is love in the equation, and what kind of love?

Answer (score -2):

http://sunnah.com/search/?q=marry+four+dust :

> Abu Huraira (Allah be pleased with him) reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
>   as saying: A woman may be married for four reasons: for her property,
>   her status. her beauty and her religion, so try to get one who is
>   religious, may your hand be besmeared with dust.